# JavaScript ignoring adding object to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, push

```
function setUsersDefinitions(data, userID){
    let users = new Array();
    return new Promise((resolve)=>{
        data.forEach(el => {
            if (el.id_adder === userID) {
                getUserName(el.id_added).then(u => {
                    users.push({
                        username: u,
                        locked: el.locked !== null,
                        canUnlock: el.locked === userID,
                        id: el.id_added
                    })
                }).catch(e=>{
                    console.log(e);
                })
            } else {
                getUserName(el.id_adder).then(u=>{
                    users.push({
                        username: u,
                        locked: el.locked !== null,
                        canUnlock: el.locked === userID,
                        id: el.id_adder
                    })
                }).catch(e=>{
                    console.log(e);
                })
            }
        })
        resolve(users);
    })
}
```

The problem is that when i try doing a console.log of the item generated it works but when it call Array.push method, it ignore that command.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It does not ignore the push, you are probably just looking for it too soon. You must wait for the promises to resolve. Notice how you call `resolve` immediately! Also you are using the promise constructor antipattern.

Comment: Thanks you. What do you suggest to do instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of this should be done with async/await, and not by wrapping the whole lot in a `Promise` - it will hugely simplify your code:

```
async function setUsersDefinitions(data, userID){
    let users = new Array();
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        var el = data[i];
        var id = (el.id_adder === userID) ? el.id_added : el.id_adder;
        var u = await getUserName(id);
        users.push({
                     username: u,
                     locked: el.locked !== null,
                     canUnlock: el.locked === userID,
                     id: id
                  });
    }
    return users;
}
```

(Note: Error handling omitted for brevity)

You should then `await` this function wherever you call it (must itself be within an `async` function):

```
async function doWork(){
    var users = await setUsersDefinitions(some_data, some_userID);
    console.log(users);
}
```